# Change message of invalid scope

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-passport

How can I change  invalid scope(s) provided message in Laravel Passport
[image]

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/roles-permissions-and-scopes-laravel-passport?page=1

Comment: I want to change message only @Developer

Answer (score 3):

try  to update this `render function` in `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    {
        if ($exception instanceof \Laravel\Passport\Exceptions\MissingScopeException) 
        {
          return response()->json(['message' => 'your message here']); 
          //abort(401); 
        }

        return parent::render($request, $e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch that as an `Exception` like so in **your controller**:

```php
try {

// Whatever you are doing which leads to such error.


} catch (MissingScopeException $e) {
    return response()->json(['message' => 'YOUR DESIRED MESSAGE.']);
}
```

By the way, [this is where](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/master/src/Exceptions/MissingScopeException.php#L24) leads to such exception.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using `laravel/framework v8.10.0` and `laravel/passport v10.0.1`.

If you are using Passport only for API you could change directly the throw exception in the Middleware.

Steps:

1. Go to `app/Http/Kernel.php`.
2. In the `$routeMiddleware` array you need to have the line:
   `'scope' => \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CheckForAnyScope::class`.
3. Go to the `CheckForAnyScope` middleware with Ctrl + click (Windows) or Cmd + click (MacOS).
4. In the `CheckForAnyScope` middleware go to `handle` function and before the line:
   `throw new MissingScopeException($scopes);` add your custom error response.

Example with code:

```
public function handle($request, $next, ...$scopes)
{
        if (! $request->user() || ! $request->user()->token()) {
            throw new AuthenticationException;
        }

        foreach ($scopes as $scope) {
            if ($request->user()->tokenCan($scope)) {
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        // Custom error response
        return response()->json(['success' => false, 'errors' => ['This type of user cannot do this action.'], 'data' => null]);

        // This line can be commented or deleted.
        throw new MissingScopeException($scopes);
}
```

Comment: You do not want to ever alter the vendor code as it never reflects on your production site (because composer install just freshens up the clean code from GIT)